# Getting Unknown errors in DirectShow Project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, directshow

i downloaded an direct show project from the link [GMFBridge - Multiple Graphs in DirectShow](http://www.gdcl.co.uk/gmfbridge/)

I added the following libraries

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Samples\multimedia\directshow\baseclasses\Debug\strmbasd.lib
>
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Lib\winmm.lib
>
> C:\ProgramFiles (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\lib\comsuppw.lib

When i build the project i am getting the errors:-

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual long __stdcall CBaseFilter::FindPin(unsigned short const *,struct IPin * *)" (?FindPin@CBaseFilter@@UAGJPBGPAPAUIPin@@@Z)    
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual long __stdcall CBaseFilter::FindPin(unsigned short const *,struct IPin * *)" (?FindPin@CBaseFilter@@UAGJPBGPAPAUIPin@@@Z)    GMFBridge\source.obj    GMFBridge
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual long __stdcall CBaseFilter::QueryVendorInfo(unsigned short * *)" (?QueryVendorInfo@CBaseFilter@@UAGJPAPAG@Z)         \GMFBridge\sink.obj GMFBridge
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual long __stdcall CBaseFilter::QueryVendorInfo(unsigned short * *)" (?QueryVendorInfo@CBaseFilter@@UAGJPAPAG@Z)         \GMFBridge\source.obj   GMFBridge
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual long __stdcall CBaseFilter::JoinFilterGraph(struct IFilterGraph *,unsigned short const *)" (?JoinFilterGraph@CBaseFilter@@UAGJPAUIFilterGraph@@PBG@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual long __stdcall BridgeSink::JoinFilterGraph(struct IFilterGraph *,unsigned short const *)" (?JoinFilterGraph@BridgeSink@@UAGJPAUIFilterGraph@@PBG@Z)    \GMFBridge (1)\GMFBridge\sink.obj   GMFBridge
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual long __stdcall CBaseFilter::JoinFilterGraph(struct IFilterGraph *,unsigned short const *)" (?JoinFilterGraph@CBaseFilter@@UAGJPAUIFilterGraph@@PBG@Z)    \GMFBridge\source.obj   GMFBridge
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall CBaseInputPin::CBaseInputPin(char const *,class CBaseFilter *,class CCritSec *,long *,unsigned short const *)" (??0CBaseInputPin@@QAE@PBDPAVCBaseFilter@@PAVCCritSec@@PAJPBG@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall BridgeSinkInput::BridgeSinkInput(class BridgeSink *,class BridgeStream *,class CCritSec *,long *,unsigned short const *)" (??0BridgeSinkInput@@QAE@PAVBridgeSink@@PAVBridgeStream@@PAVCCritSec@@PAJPBG@Z)  \GMFBridge\sink.obj GMFBridge
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual long __stdcall CBasePin::QueryId(unsigned short * *)" (?QueryId@CBasePin@@UAGJPAPAG@Z)   GMFBridge\sink.obj  GMFBridge
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual long __stdcall CBasePin::QueryId(unsigned short * *)" (?QueryId@CBasePin@@UAGJPAPAG@Z)   )\GMFBridge\source.obj  GMFBridge
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall CBaseOutputPin::CBaseOutputPin(char const *,class CBaseFilter *,class CCritSec *,long *,unsigned short const *)" (??0CBaseOutputPin@@QAE@PBDPAVCBaseFilter@@PAVCCritSec@@PAJPBG@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall BridgeSourceOutput::BridgeSourceOutput(class BridgeSource *,class BridgeStream *,class CCritSec *,long*,unsigned short const *)" (??0BridgeSourceOutput@@QAE@PAVBridgeSource@@PAVBridgeStream@@PAVCCritSec@@PAJPBG@Z)   \GMFBridge\source.obj   GMFBridge
```

Answer (score 3):

1. The project itself and `strmbasd` library need to be built with the same project settings to link well

   - See general advice on compiling/linking at [The March Hare FAQ](http://tmhare.mvps.org/faqs.htm#section_compile)
   - Search [MSDN DirectShow Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/windowsdirectshowdevelopment/threads/?filter=unread) with dozens of topics on compiling and linking DirectShow projects
2. The archive from GDCL website already has a pre-built binary (GMFBridge.dll) for you

Comment: sir i want to debug the code thats why i am trying to build the code myself....library and and project are built with same setting

Comment: Sir please try to build the project and tell me if it builds successfully on your side...if you can

Comment: See item `1` above. It is essential to have matching project settings to build the DLL.

Comment: by setting what do you mean?

Comment: This has been discussed so many times. Have a look [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsdirectshowdevelopment/thread/94482b75-3948-4316-96b1-3466e76b32ba/) and around at MSDN forum. Multiple topics on this problem. I also added links to the answer above.

Comment: Sir in the application i found that to open the there is code on LRESULT CMainDlg::OnBnClickedAdd(WORD /*wNotifyCode*/, WORD /*wID*/, HWND /*hWndCtl*/, BOOL& /*bHandled*/) how can i make the application take the stream from buffer instead from file?

Comment: @@Roman R. sir i downloaded a RTSP source filter from the link http://sourceforge.net/projects/rtspdirectshow/?source=dlp its again not building and its a library can you please tell me how to use it

Comment: Starting building from SDK samples which are in more or less good standing. It is Q&A site, read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and don't ask multiple unrelated questions one by one sending them everywhere and to anyone who happened to respond.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you, thank you, thank you so much Roman ( and March Hare by extension of course ). I would have voted up your answer if I was allowed to ( Not enough reputation to do so yet ). The March Hare FAQ was most definitely helpful, and particularly the 2nd answer of the question :

> You have the "Treat wchar_t as built-in type" set differently in the
>   baseclasses and the program