# Building GMFBridge applications using Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, compiler-errors, directshow

I tried to send this to [Geraint Davies](http://www.gdcl.co.uk/gjd.htm), but the email address on his Web site bounced with a "User unknown" error.

---

I'm trying to build [GMFBridge](http://www.gdcl.co.uk/gmfbridge/) and its applications from the source available on the site using Visual Studio 2015.  VS converted the project files to its new format without noticeable errors, but the build process isn't working.

I've downloaded and installed the [Windows Template Library](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wtl/) (WTL), [found `streams.h`](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9e658b57-527b-4e93-8265-d0fcda716dec/cannot-open-include-file-streamsh?forum=vclanguage) and added it to the `Include` directories (<*gripe*>why can't that be done at a **SOLUTION** level so **ALL** of the projects inherit it?</*gripe*>), and I [added `BaseClasses` as a project](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/2ee99454-2710-4dfb-b602-cdadc7a95a0a/how-can-i-get-strmbasdlib-?forum=windowsdirectshowdevelopment) to the solution with `GMFBridge` dependent on it.

The unresolved external errors linking GMFBridge, e.g. `CBaseFilter::FindPin`, went away when I corrected the [Treat wchar_t as built-in type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14020298/getting-unknown-errors-in-directshow-project) for the GMFBridge project.

Building `strmbasd.lib` generated 2 warnings because `'GetVersionExtW' was declared deprecated`.  I realize these aren't *GMFBridge* problems, but it's a nuisance they come up in building it because the `BaseClasses` library has to be build as a dependency.

There were a bunch of **GMFBridge** compilation errors in code such as this:

```
#if (NTDDI_VERSION >= NTDDI_VISTA) && !defined(_USING_V110_SDK71_) && !defined(_ATL_XP_TARGETING)
    return LCMapStringEx(lpLocaleName, dwMapFlags, lpSrcStr, cchSrc, lpDestStr, cchDest, lpVersionInformation, lpReserved, sortHandle);
#else
    // use LCMapStringEx if it is available (only on Vista+)...
    typedef int (__stdcall *PFNLCMAPSTRINGEX)(LPCWSTR, DWORD, LPCWSTR, int, LPWSTR, int, LPNLSVERSIONINFO, LPVOID, LPARAM);
    IFDYNAMICGETCACHEDFUNCTIONTYPEDEF(L"kernel32.dll", PFNLCMAPSTRINGEX, "LCMapStringEx", pfLCMapStringEx)
    {
        return (*pfLCMapStringEx)(lpLocaleName, dwMapFlags, lpSrcStr, cchSrc, lpDestStr, cchDest, lpVersionInformation, lpReserved, sortHandle);
    }

    // ...otherwise fall back to using LCMapString.
    return LCMapStringW(_AtlDownlevelLocaleNameToLCID(lpLocaleName), dwMapFlags, lpSrcStr, cchSrc, lpDestStr, cchDest);
#endif
```

It looked to me as though the wrong branch was probably being taken by the compiler.  When I added `_USING_V110_SDK71_` to the C++ preprocessor directives, *that* set of problems went away, but I'm sure hacking the compiler version is not the correct solution.

I've still got 48 compilation errors building the **GMFPlay** and **GMFPreview** applications.  They look like they are all due to `HMONITOR`, `MONITORINFO` and `MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST` being undefined.  I found a page on *social.msdn* re. [Build Errors after Converting project from vs2005 to vs2010](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f9947878-d89e-4c53-ad3d-9cc603ab1060/build-errors-after-converting-project-from-vs2005-to-vs2010?forum=vcmfcatl) where the suggested solution was to set `WINVER=0x0500` which I tried, but that yielded "`WINVER` redefined" warnings - and, as I expected, didn't solve anything.  I searched the [MSDN DirectShow Forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/home?forum=windowsdirectshowdevelopment&brandIgnore=True&sort=relevancedesc&searchTerm=MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST) for `MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST` and all *that* turned up was two unanswered questions.

At this point, I'm at a loss as to how to fix these problems, Web searches seem to not be yielding useful results.  Am I not asking the right question?

---

As [Roman R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/868014/roman-r) has pointed out in [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14020298/getting-unknown-errors-in-directshow-project), there are pre-built binaries on the [GMFBridge](http://www.gdcl.co.uk/gmfbridge/) site, so this exercise is largely moot right now.  However, as the OP in the above-mentioned article pointed out, debugging *into* the GMFBridge code requires having more than just the DLL available for linking.  In addition, fixing these problems *now* will make adapting the code to future architectures (128 bits anyone?) a *lot* easier than if they're just swept under the rug...